# Android Custom Galary View not scroll

Tags: android

I am using Custom Galary view in android. Each row contain a TextView with Image. When i want to scroll the Galary List then a problem created.

If I touch the Text part then i am able to scroll the List successfully. But when i try to scroll touching on the ImageView , then it is not supported.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to implement ONCLickListener() on Gallery view it will scroll on both the touch events.

Comment: Thank you for your ans. I have solved my problem. Actually i have called OnClieckListener from Adapter class . After removing this onClickListener the GalaryView scroll successfully.